# Prompting a user to exit with -1 as the condition

Tags: java, loops, exit, prompt

Im having trouble figuring out what loop to use and where to place it so that it prompts a user for an input. If the input is -1 it should exit the program if its not rerun the code, prompt for variables again and create a new object. The part im not getting is i want to loop the entire code but prompt at the end, any ideas? i'd like to prompt after change1.getChange()

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the bill amount: ");
    double billAmount = kb.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter the tendered amount:");
    double cashGiven = kb.nextDouble();
    double change = cashGiven - billAmount;
    while (billAmount > cashGiven) {
        System.out.println("Error! Not enough moula amigo, try again.");
        System.out.println("Enter the bill amount: ");
        billAmount = kb.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the tendered amount:");
        cashGiven = kb.nextDouble();
    }
    MakeChange change1 = new MakeChange(billAmount, cashGiven);

    System.out.printf("The change was %1.2f. Which is made up of:\n", change);
    change1.getChange();

    kb.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want a do-while loop,

```
double billAmount = 0;
    do {
        //your code here

       
    } while (billAmount != -1.0);
```

Also, you can't re-open a scanner once it has been closed, so put the initialization and closing outside the loop.